# Configure netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

There is a Cloud Service project. It uses netTcpBinding. Error at startup:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
Although the def file specifies this endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="TestCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="TestService" vmsize="Standard_D1_v2">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="tcp" port="63492" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

How do I configure Cloudservice for netTcpBinding correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the net.tcp port on the cloud service server.

Open IIS on your cloud service. Click the bindings to enter the add binding interface.
[image]

Select the net.tcp type.

[image]

Finally, specify the port number for it.

[image]

Comment: Only http and https are available in the cloud service...